# Best practices for iOS fetch request

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afnetworking

I've subclassed `AFHTTPSessionManager` for making requests. I have a model class for parsing my incoming JSON.

Where should I do the fetch request? Inside my model, ViewController or should I use a wrapper for the request?

Which are best practices in this cases?

Comment: Hey Carlos, there are many people here willing to help, but please make sure you've showed what you've tried, what didn't work, and the context of your question. Also make sure you've read [**how-to-ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and then edit your question to better attract people's expenditure of time and effort. As it stands, it's going to be tough to give you a finite answer, and answers are likely to be entirely opinion-based.

Comment: i believe his question more about OOP principles then actual implementation.

Comment: Are you actually using RestKit? What is the general outline of the app and the data it uses / synchronisation it makes?

Comment: @Wain I just using AFNetworking, and getting data (JSON) asynchronously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same question before when starting out my project. I did it like this:

`Base Class` that did all the fetch / put HTTP requests, using AFNetworking. 
`Web service class` that knew nothing about the base class - just how to use it, I made methods generic in that sense. 
`Data class` that constructed the url / parameters that I needed for the request.

With this way, the rest of the app knew nothing about the networking layer. The data class knew how to put the URL / Parameters together and request a network call. that's it. The web service class knows how to make that call based on the information provided to it, from the data class and the base class knows how to make the request, get the response.

I then handed the response off to a base XML / JSON class which started parsing the data it got back from the base web service class. Once the data had been parsed it is stored into the data class used the correct model objects needed. From there - the app just asks the data class for data.

With this approach, the top layer of the app knows how to request for data and get it back. It knows nothing about the internal working of that process. This means, in future, should I decided to change to a different networking library, I just need to modify one class and not a whole bunch of code.

In a nut shell I constructed it like this:

- ViewController class or some other class asks for data from the `Data class`
- `Data Class` then constructs the URL and parameters needed for the request
- `Webservice class` taken the URL and parameters from the `Data Class` and puts it into a request then sends it to the base web service class
- `Base webservice class` then makes to call with the full URL. It handles the response and should it be successful, it puts it into an `NSData` object - which is then handed off to the XML / JSON class
- The XML /JSOn class know how to handle the data object and starts the parsing. Once done, it gives it back to the `Data class` stored as a custom NSObject.

Once the class that made the original call gets notified that the http request and parsing has been completed has been completed, it then asks the `Data class' for that data.

This separation of classes and their responsibilities, works well for the reasons I stated above. Changing one part of the app, won't require a massive rewrite of many classes. At two, most.

I hope this puts you in the right direction.

Comment: Great explanation. I'm working on a similar project, but am just using NSURLConnection. I did something similar with two levels of abstraction. Anytime I need to add new functionality, my connection class never changes and I just have to tweak protocols and specific functionality for my new methods. Highly recommend Tander's approach.

Comment: That's the whole idea. When you need to scale up - your network layer stays untouched. The only time it must be changed is if you change the library or use NSURLConnection instead. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much Tander, it is exactly what I was looking for. Now I understand the theoretical side, but I think I will need more than an example to put it into practice. I found the way you separate the network side from the app very interesting, and a good way to keep light ViewControllers and MVC.

Comment: My pleasure dude. If you want more help pop me a mail and I'll give you some examples and deeper explanations etc. tanderza@gmail.com

Comment: @Tander hey man can I email you for some examples on how did you implement the above to put it into practice, I really like the way you do it!

Comment: @MKAlatrash Yes, sure you can. Tandoors@gmail.com